# What's the domain and range of time-reversal operator in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra, time-evolution

I haven't found a rigorous definition of the time-reversal operator and here are my questions.

1. What's the **definition** of a time-reversal operator? Is it an operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? Are there any operators simillar to this which are taught in mathematical courses such as linear algebra or real analysis?
2. What's the relation between time-reversal operator and **group representation theory**? Or can we define a time-reversal operator by a representation of some group?
3. Is this formula $TtT^{-1}=-t$ correct, where $t$ is the time coordinate?

Actually I know $T$ is an anti-linear operator but it's so strange and rare that I don't know how to describe it.

Comment: $T$ is an anti-linear map, not an operator: $T (\lambda \left| \psi \right> ) = \lambda^{*} T \left| \psi \right>$, while for an operator $P (\lambda \left| \psi \right>) = \lambda P \left| \psi \right>$. Also, what is $t$ in your 3rd point? The time coordinate? It is not an operator so I'm not sure how to interpret your formula.

Comment: Yes, $t$ in the third point is the time coordinate.